# Javascript array .push is not creating array items

Tags: javascript, jquery

Clicking on the list from down should save the item to an array in local storage.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( 'ul.namelist>li' ).on( "click", function() {
   var items  = [];    
   items.push( $( this ).text() );
   localStorage.setItem("items",items);     
   });
})
```

HTML

```
<ul class="namelist">
 <li>John</li>
 <li>Leena</li>
 <li>Paul</li>
 <li>Vaughn</li>
 <li>Aneel</li>
 <li>Jason</li>
</ul>
```

This code stores only last clicked name in the array where as I am trying to store all clicks in it as [John,Paul,Leena] etc. Please help.

Comment: `localStorage` can only store strings. Try `localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items))`. Of course, each time you click an `<li>`, you will only ever store an array of length `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your clicks are overriding the stored data in every click, you may need to fetch the existing store and update it before pushing a new one.

Also, your localStotrage would only store `strings` so you would need to convert the array to a string before storing it.

```
$( 'ul.namelist>li' ).on( "click", function() {
    var items  = localStorage.get('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.get('items')) : [];    
    items.push( $( this ).text() );
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));     
});
})
```

Comment: Have to stringify the array also to set in storage

Comment: @charlietfl Right, had missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage holds data as a string, so, do JSON.stringify() before storing it to local storage. Also, fetch the current state from storage before making any updates.

```
$('ul.namelist>li').on("click", function() {
    var items = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];
    items.push($(this).text());
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
});
```